# Sidebar should float on top on mobile - but not in desktop

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

Before I start a new project I would like to know if it's possible to have a sidebar that is sliding on mobile and tablets.  But on desktop it would be always on screen and the sidebar would be a part of the main container, as seen below.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-9"> </div> 
 <div class="col-md-3" id="sidebar"> </div>
 </div>
```

The thing is that I'm not sure how I would do this, would I use media queries or Jquery for example to get my desired effect

Comment: Yea it's posiable

Comment: Definitely go with media queries.

Comment: Nice to know... Can you give me an brief example.

Comment: Actually, I just saw that you're already using jQuery, so maybe there's a better way I don't know of (I don't use jQuery all that much), but for regular queries, something like`@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){.sidebar{oveflow:auto}}` and then on desktop `@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px){.sidebar{overflow: hidden}}`

Comment: Or more appropriately, style your classes differently for desktop (large screen) and mobile (small screen) and make it so it doesn't use `overflow` to achieve it (I only used it as a quick example)

Answer (score 0):

Your possible code here: maybe it helps your development.

you can try this:

```css
.content {
  background: gray;
  min-height: 100vh;
  order: 2
}

#sidebar {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
}
 
#sidebar.show { 
  transform: inherit;
  display: block;
  background: red;
}
.hambarger {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #sidebar {
    display:none;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  .hambarger {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid d-flex w-100">
 <div class="col content">
  <button class="hambarger" onclick="document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('show')">menu</button>
 </div> 
 <div class="col-md-3" id="sidebar"> </div>
</div>
```

**== Thanks ==**

Answer (score 0):

As of your Question I think you are using bootstrap and bootstap has his one navbar which does the same thing you searching for !!

[Bootstap 4v Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

Also you can do it by scratch using media queries and css !!
or Jquery

```
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 900) {
       //select the element and style it
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at following example: 
Using bootstrap 4.3 with little custom css.
To see the left side alignment try visualizing the snippet in full screen mode.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  
  .sidebar a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .sidebar a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  .sidebar .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  
  #main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
  }
  
  .hamburger {
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer font-size: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 0;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidebar {
      padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidebar a {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  }
</style>

<div id="main" class="row p-0">
  <span id="hamburger" class="hamburger d-md-none" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
  <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar col-lg-3 p-0">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn d-md-none" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9 p-0 text-center">
    This is the content area
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    document.getElementById("hamburger").style.display = "none";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("hamburger").style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @Slowboy here is an improvement to the previous version. Hope this helps.